# Couchbase parameterized query with numeric values

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm trying to add numeric values to parameterized `AnalyticsQuery` but keep getting errors when the query runs. The java creating the query looks like this:

```
  private ParameterizedAnalyticsQuery aggregateQuery(String userId, Long from, Long to) {
    return AnalyticsQuery.parameterized(
        "select d.field1,"
            + " d.field2"
            + " from data d"
            + " where d.userId = $userId"
            + " and d.timestamp between $from and $to",
        JsonObject.create()
            .put("userId", userId)
            .put("from", from)
            .put("to", to)
    );
  }
```

When the query is run the following error is returned:

```
<< Encountered \"from\" at column 213. ","code":24000}]
```

If I change the query to the following then it works and returns rows:

```
    return AnalyticsQuery.parameterized(
        "select d.field1,"
            + " d.field2"
            + " from data d"
            + " where d.userId = $userId"
            + " and d.timestamp between " + from
            + " and " + to,
        JsonObject.create()
            .put("userId", userId)
    );
```

Why is there a problem when the parameters are not Strings? Is there a way to use parameterized queries with numeric values?

Comment: I just tried this in .NET too. My guess is that between/and either can't be parameterized (yet) or there is a bug.

Comment: I'm trying it myself, I will come back to you soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FROM and TO are reserved keywords in N1QL for Analytics and therefore must be put in backquotes when used as parameter names:

```
... and d.timestamp between $`from` and $`to`
```

For a list of all reserved keywords please see:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/appendix_1_keywords.html

Comment: One other thing I noticed (in .NET anyway), is that I had to use a named parameter of "$from" instead of just "from".